# Delete my unison folder cant find how to sync again all

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, files, unison

I run unison sync and it works perfect, but accidentally dropped the folder and now I cannot recover it. I tried to run unison again, but it returned

> Nothing to do: replicas have not changed since last sync. Can I run
>   unison again and create a new folder for sync?

This is the command I used for the first time sync:

```
unison  /Users/XXX/Documents/server  ssh://kross@XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX//var/www/html/
```

this is the history log

```
Connected [//antp//var/www/html/test3 -> //juan//Users/TheThree/Documents/server]
Looking for changes
Warning: No archive files were found for these roots, whose canonical names are:
    /Users/TheThree/Documents/server
    //antp//var/www/html/test3
This can happen either
because this is the first time you have synchronized these roots,
or because you have upgraded Unison to a new version with a different
archive format.

Update detection may take a while on this run if the replicas are
large.

Unison will assume that the 'last synchronized state' of both replicas
was completely empty.  This means that any files that are different
will be reported as conflicts, and any files that exist only on one
replica will be judged as new and propagated to the other replica.
If the two replicas are identical, then no changes will be reported.

If you see this message repeatedly, it may be because one of your machines
is getting its address from DHCP, which is causing its host name to change
between synchronizations.  See the documentation for the UNISONLOCALHOSTNAME
environment variable for advice on how to correct this.

Donations to the Unison project are gratefully accepted:
http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison

Press return to continue.[<spc>]   Waiting for changes from server
Reconciling changes
Nothing to do: replicas have not changed since last sync.
```

Comment: You droppen which folder? Please paste the relevant output of `history` command

Comment: The one that i clone into my local desktop, i drop it and i cant replica again in another name folder

Comment: @shodanshok i already add the log